# Laravel Queue handle problem with Supervisor

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord

I'm working at a project which has too many job workers. The workers manages by Supervisor. Sometimes the one job which is most important job does fail without running `failed` method on Queue class. I retry work a failed job in the `failed_jobs` table by `php artisan queue:retry [job-id]` it does fail again. Also, I want to print something on the `failed` method of Queue class but the `failed` method never works.

But, the job works successfully when I restart the Supervisor process.

But why/how? What is the problem?

How it works successfully when I restarted the Supervisor if there are any error on code base?

The Laravel version is 5.1 and it works under the Ubuntu/Nginx.

The Supervisor program configs are at the following;

```
command=/usr/bin/php7.0 -d register_argc_argv=On /var/www/project-path/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon              ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
numprocs=4                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
;directory=/tmp                ; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
;umask=022                     ; umask for process (default None)
;priority=999                  ; the relative start priority (default 999)
autostart=true                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
;startsecs=1                   ; # of secs prog must stay up to be running (def. 1)
;startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures when starting (default 3)
autorestart=true        ; when to restart if exited after running (def: unexpected)
;exitcodes=0                   ; 'expected' exit codes used with autorestart (default 0)
;stopsignal=QUIT               ; signal used to kill process (default TERM)
;stopwaitsecs=10               ; max num secs to wait b4 SIGKILL (default 10)
;stopasgroup=false             ; send stop signal to the UNIX process group (default false)
;killasgroup=false             ; SIGKILL the UNIX process group (def false)
user=www-data                   ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
redirect_stderr=true          ; redirect proc stderr to stdout (default false)
stdout_logfile=/var/www/project-path/storage/logs/supervisor-stdout.log        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
;stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stdout_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stdout logfile backups (0 means none, default 10)
;stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stdout_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stdout writes (default false)
stdout_syslog=true           ; send stdout to syslog with process name (default false)
stderr_logfile=/var/www/project-path/storage/logs/supervisor-stderr.log        ; stderr log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
;stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stderr_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stderr logfile backups (0 means none, default 10)
;stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stderr_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stderr writes (default false)
;stderr_syslog=false           ; send stderr to syslog with process name (default false)
;environment=A="1",B="2"       ; process environment additions (def no adds)
;serverurl=AUTO                ; override serverurl computation (childutils)
```

Also, The Supervisor log mechanism doesn't work. It doesn't print any log to the following log file which my defined.

```
stderr_logfile=/var/www/project-path/storage/logs/supervisor-stderr.log
stdout_logfile=/var/www/project-path/storage/logs/supervisor-stdout.log
```

Also, I'm not sure there is any relation, but I want to give all details. So There is a cronjob which works every minutes.

`* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.0 /var/www/project-path/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

I spend to much time for solving that problem but, I couldn't understand that problem. I'm sure there are too much hero who can help me.

Comment: do you have any error logs or something?

Comment: Does the job time out by any chance?

Comment: @PavelLint Like I said, Supervisor logs doesn't work. Yes I have some logging system on my Job, but it never printing because of the ``handle`` method of job class doesn't work.

Comment: @PtrTon It is inserting directly to the ``failed job`` table. But, It works when I restart the Supervisor tasks.